Google Sheets, return a "x" or "y" Value if Column A is between 2 numbers
I'm trying to write a formula in column D, that will input either a "10" or "25", based on the Day number from column A
If A is between 10 - 24, in Column D, I want it to output "10" or
if A is between 25 - 9, I want it to output 25
Sheet and Formula screenshot


Here's the current formula in D2:D3
=IF(and(A2>=10,A2<=24), 10, if(and(A2>=25,A2<=9), 25))
D3 outputs the desired #, Where D2 does not
What am I doing wrong?

2 things : [1] "between 10 - 24" & "between 25 - 9" overlap on each other. Range for evaluation should not have overlap, [2] in the second IF statement the ">=" & "<=" is misplaced. "A2>=25" will be true & "A2<=9" will be false for D2, that's y the statement is false. The condition should be "and(A2<=25,A2>=9)" right?

Seems to be solved at this CROSSPOST here

Thank you, I was thinking of it based on calendar dates... i.e, August 10 - August 24th and from August 25th till September 9th

Care to post an answer, Hungry Gnome?
